# Robust estimator of the spread in 2D

Tags: robust, scale-estimator

In the 1D case, the interquartile interval is a robust estimator of the spread/scale.

Is there a 2D generalization ?

Comment: More than one. Arguably the best match (though not the most robust to outliers) would be the [bagplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagplot).

Comment: Last week at the JSM, Randal Verbrugge described an intuitively appealing method of robust estimation of covariance matrices, which could be considered an $n$-dimensional generalization.  See https://ww2.amstat.org/meetings/jsm/2017/onlineprogram/AbstractDetails.cfm?abstractid=324606 for the abstract.

Comment: @user603: the bag in the bagplot looks like what I am after.

Answer (score 2):

The Tuckey half-space depth of a point denotes the smallest number of points from the data set contained in a half-space delimited by a plane through the given point.

This looks like a clean generalization of the rank in 1D, and the key idea is to consider the direction of the plane that yields the *smallest number*.

In 2D, this direction is particularly simple to determine: after sorting the points by polar angle around the target point, a single sweep operation determines all the possible counts in $O(n)$ steps.

This concept of depth can be used to obtain a robust "kernel" of points, by considering the $\dfrac n2$ points with the largest depth. It also defines a robust "center", which is the deepest point.

[image]

[image]